# How (un)senseful would you rate this PHP code:

Tags: php, require-once

At another place, I am discussing the following issue:

I think this code:

```
if(file_exists("amodule.inc.php")) 
     require_once("amodule.inc.php");
```

is MISLEADING because of the use of the `require_once`.

I think that - to keep the logic and "wording" in line - "include_once" would be appropriate.

As far as my understanding goes, the ONLY difference between "require" and "include" is that "require has a consequence (halt) if the file does not exist vs. include proceeds with just a warning.

But, if the file does not exists, the require_once code will not executed. Therefor the "require" misleads from my point of view.

From a superficial view, one could argue that the above code using require_once and

```
if(file_exists("amodule.inc.php")) 
     include_once("amodule.inc.php");
```

are "identical" what, from my view, is not. Because:

A "rough" analysis (like an automated check of a project) would throw a message, that "amodule.inc.php" is a vital project file, which the code shows, is not.

So, how would you guys out there argue?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Flaged to close the question because it's opinion based. Questions like this belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: stackoverflow is mainly for concrete questions :/ This is not a platform for discussion, please ask questions which are "solveable"

Comment: you are right! either remove the `if` or use `include_once`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider visit deceze's answer. I don't think this is opinion-based

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the file exists and then including/requiring it is nonsense. First of all it doubles your disk access, making the operation twice as slow as it needs to be. Secondly, you may have race condition problems in which the file is deleted right between the `file_exists` and `include` call, producing errors. If the include is allowed to fail, simply use `include` without prior `file_exists` check. If the include is not allowed to fail, use `require`. That's exactly why these two constructs exist. Use `@` to optionally suppress notices.

But why would a file include be allowed to fail in the first place?

Comment: +1 for mentioning race conditions.. I thought that *I* am too pedantic :)

Comment: It's arguably extremely unlikely, but hey, as long as we're talking about *correctness*, this is a big part of it. :)

Comment: yes definitely..  and as life goes, it is unlikely but it will happen

Comment: it could be by design that an include fails.. lets say you try to include an optional plugin, but don't want to accept the race condition mentioned above.

Comment: I'd argue that it's still bad design. If you have a plugin system, you'd likely rather iterate over a directory full of files and include the files you found. Or use an autoloader with `if (class_exists('Plugin', true))`.

Comment: yeah, maybe my thought was too fictional.. but this code is at least possible.. http://pastebin.com/X8p2nYDg ..